# Do the Treasure Maps serve any purpose?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been accumulating treasure maps as I travel Skyrim:

[image]

[image]

So do these serve any purpose? Can they actually lead me to a treasure? If so, is there anyway to interpret the location other than guessing?

Comment: The first map looks like the entryway to Windhelm.

Comment: I know where the first one is, but I can't remember the name of the tower.

Comment: The second looks like the farm due south of Whiterun.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot [Valtheim Towers](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Valtheim_Towers)?

Comment: Also, are these inside containers, or sitting about in the world? If they're in the world, what do they look like?

Comment: One more thing, anyone know if the chests are there even if you don't have the map?

Comment: @agf I confirmed it - it is Valtheim towers - though it's a little tricky, the map isn't facing the direction that follows the path. Basically, you have to go to the other side and look at it from that perspective.

Comment: @spugsley Where did you find those maps? I've yet to encounter any. I also went to both the locations shown on those maps and couldn't find any treasure, so the chests appear not to be there until something has happened (my guess is, until you find the map?)

Comment: @agf I found them on some random bandits when I looted their bodies. I took them and had them in my inventory for awhile before I figured out what to do with them...not sure if actually having it in your inventory is what triggers it or not but that would be my guess. I haven't found any since these two and there are supposedly ten. They seem to be fairly uncommon. Just keep killing those bandits, I guess :)

Comment: Note: You must have the map in your possession in order to find the treasure. If you go searching for it without the map, it simply will not be there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, if you can figure out where they're pointing, they'll lead you to a chest!

See this from [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/mb1nc/treasure_map/).

I'd link directly to the image, but it's *huge*. Bottom line, there are at least 10 of these, each of which leads to a randomly generated chest of loot. (The location isn't random. The contents *are*.)

Comment: That image is extremely helpful! Thank you! I am so pleased that I actually get to use a treasure map.

Comment: also, the chests won't be there unless you have the map

Answer (score 7):

The treasure maps **WILL** lead you to treasure.  It is up to you to decipher the location.

The image depicted in the lower map is the windmill south of Whiterun.  The treasure is on the moutainside nearby,

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the treasure map causes the treasure to appear at the shown location. After reading the map, you can toss it and the treasure will still be there. The map doesn't technically have to be in your inventory, but I would suggest keeping it until you find the treasure, just in case.